# Would Popper have argued that a coin toss is indeterministic?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, probability, popper

I know that Popper was an adovcate of the propensity theory of probability, i.e. probabilities are understood as properties of sets of generating conditions. Furthermore I (think) I have read that Popper closely related the propensity theory to indeterminism. My question is whether he e.g. also thought that the outcome of a coin toss is essentially indeterminisitc?

Comment: For Popper's views on indeterminism see [here](http://www.informationphilosopher.com/solutions/philosophers/popper/). For anyone who accepts genuine quantum indeterminacy coin tosses, or any other processes classically sensitive to initial conditions, are random since the unlimited precision determinism requires is cut off at finite values.